# Is there a contradiction ?Can we find an example?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, functions

Can we find a $C^1$ function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

which satysfy this two conditions:

- $\exists k>0, \sigma\in(2,+\infty); f(u)\leq k |u|^{\sigma}, \forall u\in \mathbb{R}$
- $\exists c\in\mathbb{R}, \int_0^u f(s) ds\geq c, \forall u\in \mathbb{R}$

And an other $C^1$ function  $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which satisfy this two conditions:

- $\exists c\in\mathbb{R}, \int_0^u f(s) ds\geq c, \forall u\in \mathbb{R}$
- $\exists \delta>0, \int_0^{u} f(s) ds=0, \forall |u|\leq \delta$

Is there a contradiction with these conditions ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, I have something :
suppose that we have $k>0$
  and $\sigma>2$
  such that $f\left(u\right)\leq k\left|u\right|^{\sigma}$
  for all $u\in\mathbb{R}$
 . Suppose also that we have $c\in\mathbb{R}$
  such that$$c\leq\intop_{s=0}^{u}f\left(s\right)ds.$$
 Then, for $u>0$
 , we have$$c\leq\intop_{s=0}^{u}f\left(s\right)ds\leq k\intop_{s=0}^{u}s^{\sigma}ds=k\frac{u^{\sigma+1}}{\sigma+1}.$$
 For $u<0$
 , we have$$c\leq\intop_{s=-\left|u\right|}^{0}f\left(s\right)ds\leq k\intop_{s=-\left|u\right|}^{0}\left(-s\right)^{\sigma}ds=k\frac{\left(\left|u\right|\right)^{\sigma+1}}{\sigma+1}.$$
 Therefore, we must have for all $u\in\mathbb{R}$
 $$c\leq k\frac{\left|u\right|^{\sigma+1}}{\sigma+1}$$
 whence $c\leq0$
 . We can take $k=1$
 , $\sigma=2$
 , $c=0$
  and $f\left(u\right)=u^{2}$
  : we have$$f\left(u\right)=u^{2}\leq\left|u\right|^{2}$$
 and$$0\leq\intop_{s=0}^{u}s^{2}ds=\frac{u^{3}}{3}$$
 if $u>0$
  and $$0\leq\intop_{s=-\left|u\right|}^{0}s^{2}ds=-\frac{\left(-\left|u\right|\right)^{3}}{3}=\frac{\left|u\right|^{3}}{3}$$
 if $u<0$
 . I think all is correct.

Comment: I took $\sigma=2$, but $\sigma=4$ is ok with $f\left(u\right)=u^{4}$.

Comment: Thank you i used $\sigma=3$ and $k=2$ and $f(u)=u^3$ and $c=0$.

Comment: For the second example i tried $f(u)=u^3-\frac14$, $c=-1/2$ and $\delta=1$ are you ok ?

Comment: I am not sure that you condition $$\intop_{0}^{\delta}f\left(s\right)ds=0$$ for all $\left|u\right|\leq\delta$ is satisfied. But we can try$$f\left(u\right)=\begin{cases} 0 & \textrm{if\,}-1\leq u\leq1\\ \exp\left(-\frac{1}{u^{2}-1}\right) & \textrm{if\,}\left|u\right|\geq1 \end{cases}$$ for $\delta=1$ and $c\leq0$ ?

Comment: see $\int_{0}^1(u^3-\frac14)=\frac14 u^4-\frac14 u|^1_0=0$

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Usciw.png

Comment: Yes for $u=1$, but your condition was for all possible values between $-1$ and $1$ : for example, if $u=1/2$, it is not true.

Comment: the second id $\int_0^{\delta}...$ not $\int_0^u...$ for $u=1$

Comment: Oh sorry! I was thinking to $$\intop_{0}^{u}f\left(s\right)ds=0.$$But now, why are you precised for all $\left|u\right|\leq\delta$ since your last condition does not depend on any $u$ ?

Comment: ohhh sorry sorry it is for all $|s|\leq \delta$

Comment: So that's fine for me :)

Comment: see what i want is that $\int_0^u f(s) ds=0$ when $|u|\leq \delta$  i think that my condition is not right what do think ?

Comment: for the condition $\int_0^u f(s) ds, |u|\leq \delta$ my example is not true

Comment: Let us move onto the chat to avoid to long comments ;)